# How do I convert JsonResult to a model in MVC.NET?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, model

I am trying to convert JsonResult object to a model.
I've seen few example which converts Json strings to model, but wasn't quite sure how I would convert JsonResult object.
I was trying to use ConvertToType but wasn't successful.
What am I doing wrong?

```
public ActionResult Search(string keyWord)
{    
    var result = new JsonResult
    {
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
        Data = _featuresSearch.Search(keyWord)
    };

    JavaScriptSerializer objJavascript = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    _SearchResult model = objJavascript.ConvertToType<_SearchResult>(result);
    return View("SearchResult", model);
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do. Why are you using `JsonResult` and `JavaScriptSerializer`? - why not just `var model = _featuresSearch.Search(keyWord); return View("SearchResult", model);`?

Comment: Look at data contracts

Comment: Thank you very much, Stephen and jumpingcode, as you both suggested, I've reviewed it, and simple change the data model instead of using JsonResult to make it work. 
Thank you, much appreciated.